# background in hexagon overflow

Tags: html, css, background-image

How can i make sure my hexagon allows overflow of the background image?

I created hexagons with the following code:

--- **css** ---

```
#color5 {
   background-image: url(http://URL/images/Logo.jpg);
   background-color:purple;
   z-index:1;
}
#hex3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.hexagon-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hexagon {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% * 0.57735);
  display: inline-block;
}

.hexagon:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: calc((100% / 2) - ((100% * 0.57735) / 2));
  background-color: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  z-index:-1;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(60deg);
}

.hexagon:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: calc((100% / 2) - ((100% * 0.57735) / 2));
  background-color: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  content: '';
  z-index:-1;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-60deg);
}
```

** HTML**

```
    <div id="eventinfo">
        <div id="hex3" class="hexagon-wrapper">
            <div id="color5" class="hexagon"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this gives me the following result:
[image: result]

where off course i want: 
[image]

how can i achieve this? I have no clue and am totally lost, Google doesn't show anything useful in my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I have used an example from a csstricks article, that achieves what you are trying to do using clip-path

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
```

http://codepen.io/Vall3y/pen/GgRVva

Here's the full article
http://css-tricks.com/sketchy-avatars-css-clip-path/